# Form inheritance in Visual Studio 2008 doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Is there a way to fix "The service Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.ISelectionContainer already exists in the service container. Parameter name: serviceType" in VS2008? I just create an empty form, then create form that inherits the first one. When I try to open the inherited form, this message appears.

Update:

1. Tried restarting VS
2. Tried rebuilding solution
3. Tried re-creating these forms

Doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rebuild first and then create derived form. The VS winforms designer instantiate base class and after that parse the "InitialzeComponents" and add controls on it.

Comment: It's very wired behaviour. We are using same scenario without this exception (in complex forms with many others :/).

Comment: This scenario works fine on my other computer. Just different versions of VS2008: SP (doesn't work) vs. RTM (does work).

Comment: I have SP on my VS2008 Pro, and it works :(. Have you installed some Add-ins in VS?

Comment: Well, it's only WiX I believe.

Comment: Ok. you can try one thing. Run 2 instances of VS. In first do menu->debug->attach to process and choose the second instance of VS. Press CTRL+ALT+E and check "Thrown" in exception list. In the second instance of VS open the project and try open designer of inherited form. In the first instance VS you should see the standard "Exception thrown" breakpoint and you will see exactly where is exception thrown. Maybe you will find the source of problem.