# the service microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.iselectioncontainer already exists in the service container

Tags: visual-studio

I recently installed Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate version on my machine. I'm just trying to create a sample windows form project and trying to open the designer / form by double clicking on Form1.cs and I'm getting this weird error message:

"the service microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.iselectioncontainer already exists in the service container"

My system is already having Visual Studio 2010 which is working smoothly from a long time. I then installed Visual Studio 2012 which was giving the same problem as above. So I went ahead with installing VS 2013 hoping that I might be able to get rid of this issue, but no use.

Once I click OK on the error windows, I can see the following "message" in the bottom Error List window:

"The file 'C:\Users\ABCD\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WebSite1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs' does not support code parsing or generation because it is not contained within a project that supports code."

I have spent 2-3 days searching various blogs like these, all of which talk about previous version of Visual Studio like VS 2005 / VS 2008:

> > https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/311949/the-service-microsoft-visualstudio-shell-interop-iselectioncontainer-already-exists-in-the-service-container
> >
> > [Form inheritance in Visual Studio 2008 doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841246/form-inheritance-in-visual-studio-2008-doesnt-work)

I have even tried uninstalling and reinstalling VS 2013, again no use.

It would be really great if someone can help me out in fixing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem got resolved finally, after so many days and various frustrating tries to resolve the issue. I should thank Tim Atkins from Microsoft for helping me with resolving this issue.

Fix: When we tried 'gacutil /l system.design', we found that there were 3 variants of system.design; One from .Net 2.0 targetting MSIL, second from .Net 4.0 targetting x86 and last one also from .Net 4.0, but targetting MSIL.

On a working machine, there were only 2 entries, the .Net 4.0 one targetting x86 wasn't there. Hence we uninstalled this version using gacutil which did the magic. I was so relieved seeing the win forms popping up without any errors anymore :)

Answer (score 4):

I've just had the exact same error message.

After compiling the solution(F6 or Build->Build Solution) it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this be closing VS, deleting contents of the .vs folder where my solution is, restarting VS and recompiling.
Seems like one of those file/settings/caching problems that pop up now and then, might be after switching source branch.
VS2019, .net fw 4.6.2.

Comment: XrmToolBox Bug with VS 2019?

Answer (score 0):

To deal with your issue, please first make sure that you installed latest updates on your Windows 8 machine, and then repair VS2013.

During your repairing process, please temporally turn off  your anti-virus/antispyware software and repair VS2013 with the Administrator privilege.

[follow this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2790a395-d4e5-4c06-8e9c-74431ee94e04/microsoftvisualstudioshellinteropiselectioncontainer-in-visual-studio2012?forum=vssetup)

Comment: Thanks for the response Nagaraj. Actually I had already gone through the link you shared and had tried that option, but it didn't help in fact.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the target framework from 4.5 to 4.6.1 and it fixed it for me. My assumption is sometimes when you change target framework back and forth and the process does not go through all the way (cancelling in the middle of changing it) - something happens that leads to this error. Hope that helps

Answer (score -4):

If your C drive (Where you are installing Visual Studio) does not have enough space, try moving some files from the C drive to another drives.