# Problem adding a migration to my ASP.NET Core 3.1 project

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-migrations

When I try to add a migration to my project, I get the following error:

> System.InvalidCastException: Impossible d'effectuer un cast d'un objet COM de type 'System.__ComObject' en type d'interface
> 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsAggregatableProject'. Cette
> opération a échoué, car l'appel QueryInterface sur le composant COM
> pour l'interface avec l'IID '{FFB2E715-7312-4B93-83D7-D37BCC561C90}' a
> échoué en raison de l'erreur suivante : Cette interface n’est pas
> prise en charge (Exception de HRESULT : 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
> à
> System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.ProjectExtensions.GetProjectTypes(Project
> project)    à
> System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.ProjectExtensions.IsWebSiteProject(Project
> project)    à
> System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsCommands..ctor(Object project,
> Object startUpProject, String configurationTypeName, String
> connectionStringName, String connectionString, String
> connectionProviderName, PSCmdlet cmdlet) Impossible d'effectuer un
> cast d'un objet COM de type 'System.__ComObject' en type d'interface
> 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsAggregatableProject'. Cette
> opération a échoué, car l'appel QueryInterface sur le composant COM
> pour l'interface avec l'IID '{FFB2E715-7312-4B93-83D7-D37BCC561C90}' a
> échoué en raison de l'erreur suivante : Cette interface n’est pas
> prise en charge (Exception de HRESULT : 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

This is my appsettings.json :

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "default": "Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=firstDB;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"
  }
}
```

And this is `program.cs` :

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
```

This is `startup.cs` :

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
           // services.AddControllersWithViews();
            string connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("default");
            services.AddDbContext<AppDBContext>(c => c.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
            services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDBContext>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

      app.UseAuthentication();
      app.UseAuthorization();

      app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
   }
```

So far, I haven't found any solutions that I can follow.

If anyone had this type of problem, enlighten me please.

Thank you.

Comment: looks like something is using a DLL for a com control component... you're probably missing a dependency for that.  Is there anything you are using COM for? When you say "migrating" are you migrating from old .NET framework code?  (4.xx?)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but no, i'am actually trying to add a migration for the sql server database.I'am using Package Manager Console and when i run the commande : # Add-Migration IdentityDBUser, i get the error above.

Comment: and i don't know how to know if i'm using COM for something else actually, i don't know what that is.

Comment: ok, looking into this more it's COM interop for shell, which Visual Studio uses for things like EF migrations.  You should try updating Visual Studio...  or possibly re-building the project file.  There's some component that's not working for some reason.  Maybe it's just a corrupt project file (or a file running on the wrong version of VS)

Comment: maybe check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20942505/the-service-microsoft-visualstudio-shell-interop-iselectioncontainer-already-exi

Comment: I think this is more of a VS issue. Please try to Repair Visual Studio (NOT Uninstall and Reinstall, just Repair).

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I already tried that and it didn't work.